# Негативный просмотр назад при использовании [^]

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно реализовать следующую мысль в регулярных выражениях:

> Все символы, кроме знака "=", перед которым не стоит знак "\"

Пробовал вот так, но должного эффекта не добился:

> `(?<!\\)[^=]*`

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что вам нужен парсер, а вы пытаетесь обойтись регулярками.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в вопросе подразумевается полноценная реализация экранирования, то:

https://regex101.com/r/dG3bF4/1

```
(?:\\.|[^=])+
```

Читается так:
Альтернатива из любого экранированного символа, или любого символа отличного от `=` минимум 1 раз.

---

А если просто нужно захватить все символы, или `=` перед которым нет `\`, то так:

https://regex101.com/r/dG3bF4/2

```
(?:[^=]|(?<=\\)=)+
```

Читается так: символ отличный от `=` или `=` перед которым `\` минимум один раз.

Comment: Вообще-то, `(?:[^=]++|(?<=\\)=)+` и `(?:\\.|[^=]++)+` не будет работать в .NET. Regex101 не поддерживает синтаксис регулярных выражений .NET.

Comment: Да, виноват. Не думал, что в NET нет поддержки свержадности. Спасибо.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew был на работе, зашел на сайт, когда Вашему ответу было 4 минуты :(

Comment: Простите :( Я бы не стал писать ответ, если бы у Вас изначально в совпадение включались слэши :(